# Assign Nested Value to Variable in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have an event log in Splunk that looks like this:

```
{ 
  "event": { 
    "Id":"12345",
    "Name": "My Event",
    "Inputs": {
      "Param1":"some value",
      "Param2":"another value"
    },
    "Result": {
      "statusCode":"304"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the value of the `statusCode` from the `Result` to determine what kind of error I received. Currently, I'm using the following Splunk query:

```
index="myIndex"
sourcetype="*"
| spath=event
| fields
  _time
  Name
  Result.statusCode
| eval _status="tbd"
| eval _code=statusCode
| eval _code=case(statusCode>=200 AND statusCode<300, "OK", statusCode>=300 AND statusCode<400, "Redirected", statusCode>=400 AND statusCode<500, "User Error", statusCode>500, "Server Error")
| rename
  Name as RequestName
  _code as StatusCode
  _status as Status
| table
  _time
  RequestName
  Status
  StatusCode
  Result.statusCode
```

The above is a port of the actual query in an effort to isolate the issue. Still, the issue is when I run my query, I can see:

- _time
- RequestName
- Status
- Result.statusCode

Oddly, and the part that is confusing me is, I cannot see StatusCode. I need a variable to do additional processing which is why I have the `eval _code` statement. However, I'm not having any using `Result.statusCode` as a variable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid leading underscores in  field ("variable") names as they are hidden by default.  Some can only be used after assigning their values to another field.

Also, creating a field and then renaming it is unnecessary unless the final field name will contain spaces or special characters.

It looks like something is missing from the query since only the _time and Result.statusCode fields exist, but statusCode is used often.  The `case` function will return `null` if statusCode does not exist.  The Name field also doesn't exist so I don't understand how you can see RequestName.

```
index="myIndex"
sourcetype="*"
| spath event
| fields
  _time
  Result.statusCode
| eval Status="tbd", statusCode='Result.statusCode'
| eval StatusCode=case(statusCode>=200 AND statusCode<300, "OK", 
                       statusCode>=300 AND statusCode<400, "Redirected", 
                       statusCode>=400 AND statusCode<500, "User Error", 
                       statusCode>500, "Server Error",
                       1==1, statusCode)
| rename
  Name as RequestName
| table
  _time
  RequestName
  Status
  StatusCode
  Result.statusCode
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to put `Name` in my list of fields when I copied it over. Still, my issue is with the `StatusCode`. Even if I just do a `eval MyStatusCode=statusCode` or `eval MyStatusCode=Result.statusCode`, I still do not see it in the final `table`. I do see `Result.statusCode` though.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there is no field called "statusCode" so the the `case` function assigns a null value to StatusCode.  Use `eval statusCode='Result.statusCode'` (the single quotes are required) to assign a value.  See my updated answer.  The single quotes prevent `eval` from interpreting the `.` as the concatenation operator.

Comment: The single quotes took care of it for me! Thank you!